# How to use class constants in @Security annotation using the Symfony Expression Language?

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces, expression

I am using Symfony 3 and I've created a custom Voter class.

I want to access it using the [SensioFrameworkExtraBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html) `@Security` tag.

It kind of works.

If I do the following it works perfectly:

```
 /**
 * @Rest\Get("organisation/{id}")
 * @Security("is_granted('OrgAdmin', id)")
 * @param int     $id
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return View
 */
public function getOrganisationAction($id, Request $request)
{
```

But I don't like the idea of using magic strings in the application and I would much rather use a class constant for the check.

Something like this:

```
/**
 * @Rest\Get("organisation/{id}")
 * @Security("is_granted(AppBundle\OrgRoles::ROLE_ADMIN, id)")
 * @param int     $id
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return View
 */
public function getOrganisationAction($id, Request $request)
{
```

But when I try that I get the following error message:

```
Unexpected character \"\\\" around position 20 for expression `is_granted(AppBundle\\OrgRoles::ROLE_ADMIN, id)`.
```

Which when unescaped, is the following:

```
Unexpected character "\" around position 20 for expression `is_granted(AppBundle\OrgRoles::ROLE_ADMIN, id)`.
```

So I'm stumped on this.

Can it be done?

Any suggestions on a better way to do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the [`constant()`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/syntax.html#working-with-functions) function available in the [Expression Language Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html):

```
@Security("is_granted(constant('\\Full\\Namespace\\To\\OrgRoles::ROLE_ADMIN'), id)")
```

Answer (score 15):

Doctrine annotation reader has made this even easier for constants in PHP code:

```
use MyCompany\Annotations\Bar;
use MyCompany\Entity\SomeClass;

/**
* @Foo(PHP_EOL)
* @Bar(Bar::FOO)
*/
```

This also works just as expected for @Security / @IsGranted.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-annotations/en/latest/custom.html#constants

Comment: this should be added in the accepted answer! Thanks for the information