# Use Constant in API Platform Security Annotation

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com, symfony4-voter

API Platform for Symfony allows you to use Voters in order to grant or deny access to your ressources, as described in their [docs](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/security/#hooking-custom-permission-checks-using-voters).

However all example are using magic values, I would rather use class constants for this. Ex.

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     itemOperations={
 *          "put"={"security"="is_granted(UserVoter::USER_EDIT, object)"},
 *     }
 * )
 */
```

I've tried it using an "use" statement for the `UserVoter` class, `App\Security\Voter\UserVoter::USER_EDIT` as well as escaped `App\\Security\\Voter\\UserVoter::USER_EDIT`, however nothing was accepted by API Platform

Question: How can I use class constants with security in API Platform?

Comment: I never used `ApiPlatform` yet but [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591028/how-to-use-class-constants-in-security-annotation-using-the-symfony-expression/44591217). Have you tried `\\App\\Security\\Voter\\UserVoter::USER_EDIT` or `is_granted(constant('\\App\\Security\\Voter\\UserVoter::USER_EDIT'), object)`? (_maybe for the second example the constant function will need the Expression Language Component installed, and I don't know if it is included or not in ApiPlatform package_)

Comment: Hey. did you tried `"security"="is_granted(permission(UserVoter::USER_EDIT), object)"` ? Also, show please this entity with main class annotation and its constants

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to confirm to anyone wondering:
`is_granted(constant('\\App\\Security\\Voter\\UserVoter::USER_EDIT'), object)` works a treat